# Batch vs Batched exception handling

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

I noticed a difference between batch with binder and batched.

In the binder the spring boot jooq exception translator is executed when a DataAcessException occurs in the batched case there is no translation and the exception is directly propagated.

Example:

```
final BatchBindStep batch = getDslContext().batch(
     insertInto( X ).values( (Long) null,);
     batch.bind( x ) ) ); --> with loop
     batch.execute(); --> exception with translator to spring exception
```

Example:

```
  getDslContext().batched( configuration ->
            // some loop
           insertInto( X ).values( "A").execute() --> exception goes not the translator
  );
```

How can i propagate the exception always to the spring jOOQ translator?

Also noticed that i have the same behavior if I throw a jOOQ exception directly.

```
@Transaction
public foo(){
  throw new DataAccessException(""); --> from jOOQ
}
```

Only the batch.execute() will be translated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug, I'm not quite sure yet. I've created [#14964](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14964).

The [`BatchedConnection`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/BatchedConnection.html) (made available using [`DSLContext.batched()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batched(org.jooq.BatchedRunnable)), for example) currently doesn't integrate with the [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) lifecycle. This is because it is implemented purely at the JDBC level, and can be used purely at the JDBC level, too.

The [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) lifecycle is mostly tied to jOOQ query execution, which is delayed in this case. So the lifecycle is run ordinarily when rendering queries and executing them, but things like update counts, etc. may be misleading (they're `0` at the time of adding the query to the batch, implicitly).

This means that currently, an exception originating from the delayed batch execution is not routed to any `ExecuteListener` lifecycle, because there's no query context that it could be tied to. This is probably a bug (see [#14964](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14964)), but I wonder if Spring shouldn't perhaps still be able to translate the resulting jOOQ `DataAccessException` to a Spring one. Your last example hints at this being indeed a problem worth reporting to Spring Boot? Spring Boot (to my knowledge) only has this [`JooqExceptionTranslator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jooq/JooqExceptionTranslator.java) implementation, that relies on the `ExecuteListener` lifecycle. But it could probably recognise any type of jOOQ `DataAccessException` if the `spring-boot-starter-jooq` is enabled.